# Flow Activity across async tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, open-telemetry

What is the correct way to flow an System.Diagnostics.Activity across a Task.Run that you don't want to await?

Example, I have a workflow that just informs some third party services that an event occurred, but I don't particularly care if they succeed or not, nor do I care when the notification finishes.

```
 public void NotifyExternalServices() {
     //fire and forget
     Task.Run(() => ExternalServices.NotifyOtherAll(new ThisHappenedEvent());
 }
```

That all works very well, but adding OpenTelemetry into the mix makes the telemetry very messed up since the "current" event changes.

Is this the correct pattern to use?

```
 public void NotifyExternalServices() {
     var parentActivity = MyActivitySource.StartActivity();
     //fire and forget
     Task.Run(() {
         Activity.Current = parentActivity;
         try {
            ExternalServices.NotifyOtherAll(new ThisHappenedEvent());
         } finally {
           parentActivity?.Dispose();
         }
     };
 }
```

Comment: Activities are scoped  and your code is not scoped. So you can try hacking, and it may work and may break in the future. Assigning `Activity.Current` may work, if it's done in an `async` method/lambda. But again, it might break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity.Current` is `AsyncLocal` which are flown across tasks via `ExecutionContext`.
You can explicitly capture `ExecutionContext`.

```cs
ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext.Capture()!.CreateCopy(),
    _ => Task.Run(() => { ... }), null);
```

But seems you are not showing us real code, since `Task.Run` is already capturing `ExecutionContext` in a similar manner.
You can also disable context propagation.

```cs
using (ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
    Task.Run(() => { ... });
```

Comment: In general Task.Run works just fine as you describe. But it is seen as part of the CURRENT activity. In the case you have a fire-and-forget, it ends up a problem because that task is seen as the original activity. What we want is a way to mark the task as a totally separate activity similar to making a http call.

Comment: @Cine you can just reassign `Activity.Current` inside your `Task.Run`, so they will be disconnected.